# Node express request body undefined on AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda

Im using AWS Amplify to generate Node Express rest API endpoints.

I recently added a new endpoint, but I keep getting undefined in the request body, and I can't figure out where I might have miss-configured my application.

App.js

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var awsServerlessExpressMiddleware = require("aws-serverless-express/middleware");

// declare a new express app
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(awsServerlessExpressMiddleware.eventContext());

// Enable CORS for all methods
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

var aws = require("aws-sdk");
const https = require("https");

app.post("/refresh", function(req, res){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    // {}
    console.log(JSON.parse(req.body));
    //Error: unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
});
```

I'm testing this in the AWS console with this payload

```
{
  "path": "/refresh",
  "httpMethod": "POST",
  "header": "{\"content-Type\":\"application/json\"}",
  "body": "{\"Username\":\"test\"}"
}
```

Comment: did you find any solution ? @dev.tom

Answer (score 2):

Set header as

```
"Content-Type: application/json"
```